# Get returns an array instead of an object in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get a single user instead of an entire list of users. Query is working but Get doesn't work. Is it because the user contains objects that contain arrays? For example, stores: {type: Array} instead of string in the User Schema/model

```
    $scope.init = function() {
//Users.query works fine
        Users.query({}, function(users) {
            console.log(users);
        });
// Get returns an array instead of object
        Users.get({phone:'+12223434'}, function(users2) {
            console.log(users2);
        });
    };
```

This is my $resource

```
angular.module('mean.management').factory('Users', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('/admin/users/:userId', {
            userId: '@_id'
        }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            },
            get: {method: 'GET',isArray: false} //added this line of code
        });
    }
]);
```

Comment: you dont need to specify anything specific for GET call. This should work. Can you check what your backend return?

Comment: It works if I change isArray to true... But now when I do                 users2.store.push('test'); it says 'Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'

Answer (score 0):

I've been trouble shooting this for days and figured out the answer 10 minutes after posting the question. Try changing isArray to true for your 'Get.' Good luck! Hope this solution finds someone.